# How can I specify other columns of a selected SharePoint list row in PowerApp?

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, powerapp, data

I'm making a Power App form that pulls options from a SharePoint list. The list has three columns:

- Category
- Subcategory
- Abbreviation

Users select a category and subcategory using a [cascading dropdown](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkZG2boN7jQ). Each category may have multiple subcategories and each subcategory has a unique abbreviation. Now I want to make a label that says: "You have selected [abbreviation]." In order to test something simpler, I tried setting the Text value of the label to:

```
"You have selected" & SubcategoryDropdown.SelectedText & "."
```

This returns "Invalid argument type. Expecting one of the following: Text, Number, Boolean, OptionSetValue, ViewValue." How is Selected**Text** not "Text"?! I also tried this:

```
"You have selected" & SubcategoryDropdown.Value.Abbreviation & "."
```

Same deal, just returns an error that it's invalid. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Please try as follows:

```
 "You have selected" & " " & 'SubcategoryDropdown'.Selected.Value & "."
```

Simple test for your reference:

[image]

Comment: Hi Julie, thank you for your answer. This didn't work either, but I was able to use `SubcategoryDropdown.Selected.Result` to display the current value of the SubCategory dropdown. However, what I need is to find the value of a different column of the row of the SharePoint list selected by the Subcategory dropdown. So for example if SubCategory is Alphabet, with Abbreviation ABC, I need to add "ABC" to the label, not "Alphabet".

Comment: How about using Abbreviation.selected.result directly?